# in app purchase export compliance

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I use in app purchase in my iOS app to buy more coins. I do not download data from any server. While uploading my app, apple asks me whether my app contains encryption. What should I select here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd select "No" if IAP is your only concern.

Comment: Yes IAP is the only concern